# In a function definition, how should I declare an XMLObject["Document"] argument?

Tags: argument-patterns, xml

Here we have an `XMLObject["Document"]`:

```
(* gives an XMLObject["Document"] *)
myXML = ImportString["<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN\" \"HTMLFiles/xhtml-math11-f.dtd\">
<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
<head><title>Feeling like Job today :(</title></head>
<body><p>Oh. Dear!</p></body></html>", {"XHTML", "XMLObject"}];
```

This just confirms that `x` is indeed an `XMLObject["Document"]`:

```
f1[x_] := (Echo[Head@x, "Head of arg:"]; Echo[FullForm@x, "FullForm of arg:"];)
f1[myXML]

(* Output:
Head of arg:  XMLObject[Document]

FullForm of arg:  XMLObject["Document"][List[XMLObject["Declaration"][Rule["Version","1.0"],Rule["Standalone","yes"]]],XMLElement["html",List[Rule[List["http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/","xmlns"],"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"]],List[XMLElement["head",List[],List[XMLElement["title",List[],List["Feeling like Job today :("]]]],XMLElement["body",List[],List[XMLElement["p",List[],List["Oh. Dear!"]]]]]],List[]]
*)
```

And now we try to match this as the arg type for a function:

```
f2[x_XMLObject]:=Echo["Yay, we got called!","f2:"];
f3[x_XMLObject["Document"]]:=Echo["Yay, we got called!","f3:"];
f4[x_XMLObject[type_String]]:=Echo["Yay, we got called!","f4:"];
f5[x_XMLObject[type_]]:=Echo["Yay, we got called!","f5:"];
f6[x_XMLObject[___]]:=Echo["Yay, we got called!","f6:"];

f2[myXML]
f3[myXML]
f4[myXML]
f5[myXML]
f6[myXML]

(*Expected: f2 might remain unevaluated, but f2, f3, f4, f5, f6 report getting called*)
(*Actual: f2, f3, f4, f5 remain unevaluated; f6 is invoked:
f6:  Yay, we got called!
*)
```

Regrettably, in the case of `f6`, only the head of the argument is available in the function, making `f1` with its completely untyped, unpatterned argument the only one of my attempts that worked.

Surely it is possible to write a clean, fully specified argument pattern for `XMLObject["Document"]`, and clearly I am missing something fundamental about how patterns are matched. But what?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a pattern with a condition, like:

```
MatchQ[myXML, x_ /; Head[x] == XMLObject["Document"]]

True
```

With this you may then define e.g.:

```
f1[x_ /; Head[x] == XMLObject["Document"]]:= "Yes, this is an XMLObject."

f1[myXML]

"Yes, his is an XMLObject."
```

Comment: That worked a treat, thank you very much! And while your suggestion has fixed my immediate problem, it raises another question: Shouldn’t the `x_somehead` syntax do precisely what your restriction is doing?

Comment: @FelixKasza - the issue is the precedence between the `_` and `[...]` operators.  You would think that `x_XMLObject["Document"]` is the same as `x_(XMLObject["Document"])` but really it's equivalent to `(x_XMLObject)["Document"]`.

Comment: @JasonB. -- I feel a little stupid, but very much enlightened now. Thank you! I am off to try this!

Answer (score 3):

This is a syntax issue with the pattern notation. Consider this from your `f3`:

```
FullForm[x_XMLObject["Document"]]
(* Pattern[x,Blank[XMLObject]]["Document"] *)
```

So, your "pattern" isn't actually a well-formed pattern, it's an expression with a pattern as its head. I'm not even sure what that would match. Instead, try something like this:

```
f3[x : XMLObject["Document"][___]] := ...
```

Or something like this:

```
f3[x_?(EqualTo[XMLObject["Document"]]@*Head)] := ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll certainly remember to look at the FullForm of patterns I have problems with! The ":" notation by itself does not cure my badly-constructed pattern (I had tried those variations before posting), but I think with this together with Jason B.'s comment above, I may better understand my error.